# Groovy - get map values for a list of keys

Tags: groovy

Instead of getting a map value for a key, how to get all values for a list of keys, or set of keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
def map = [1:"A", 2:"B", 3:"C", 4:"D"]
def keySet = [1, 2, 3]

assert ['A', 'B', 'C'] == keySet.collect{map[it]}
assert ['A', 'B', 'C'] == map.collectMany{k,v -> k in keySet ? [v] : []}
assert ['A', 'B', 'C'] == map.findResults{k,v -> k in keySet ? v : null}
```

If I spend some time for this question there will be few other ways. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for convenient methods like powerful `Python` slicing. In `groovy` for that present method `subMap` which take list of keys:

```
Map m = [one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4]

m.subMap(['two', 'three'])
// Off course with groovy flexible syntax you may do simple:
m.subMap('two', 'three')
// Or even:
m.subMap 'two', 'three', 'non-existent'
```

Both variants will return `['two':2, 'three':3]`.

There no errors will be if we request non-existent key also.

As argument, you may really provide any collection not only `List`, for example `Range` also may be very useful.

Some additional examples you may found in Klein Ikkink blog post: http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2009/10/groovy-goodness-getting-submap-from-map.html